# Is this correct? 用实际行动来（回馈）父母的期待。

Tags: vocabulary, phrase

Is "用实际行动来（回馈）父母的期待" correct?

I think "回馈期待" is unnatural to me.

If it is wrong, would "回报" be correct?

What other words can be used here? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

馈 means "to gift"

报 means "to repay"

回馈 means "to give back (to shows your gratitude)

回报 means "to repay" (a grace or debt)

> "用实际行动来（回馈）父母的期待"
>
> 实际行动 is not a gift
>
> It would be correct to write: "用(成果)来（回馈）父母"
>
> *成果 is a gift; object of 回馈 is the parents, not their expectation*

~

> 用实际行动来（回报）父母的期待"
>
> 期待 is not a grace or debt
>
> It would be correct to write: "用实际行动来（回报）父母的(恩情)"
>
> *恩情 is a grace; the object of 回报 is 父母的恩情*

~

> 回应 means "to respond"
>
> Better change "用实际行动来（回馈）父母的期待" to "用实际行动来（**回应**）父母的期待"
>
> "*Use action to respond to his parent's expectation*"

More example:

- 回馈社會 (give back to the society) *the object of 回馈 is the society, not what the society has done for you*
- 回报親恩 (repay the parents' grace)
- 回应訴求 (respond to appeal)

Answer (score 0):

> 用实际行动来（回馈）父母的期待

回馈 is more accurate than 回报 in this context.

回馈 means 回应/回答 feedback or 回应馈赠 feedback with reward. It means *feedback* in this context.

回报 means 回应和报答，response and pay back.

Answer (score 0):

用实际行动来 回馈 父母的期待。（sounds OK according to people I asked.)
You should use practical action to fulfill your parents expectations (of you).

用实际行动来 实现 父母的期待。

You should use practical action to live up to your parents' expectations of you.
你应该用实际的行动来达到你父母的期望。